# Odd table cell width behavior

Tags: html, css, html-table, width, percentage

This code ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rena92oo/)):

```
<table style="border:1px solid black;width:auto;">
<tr>
 <td style="width:100%;">hello.</td>
 <td style="width:100%;">World</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

produces a table expanded to the width of the window, with the first `td` expanding to fill. The second `td` remains at its minimum size.

According to the CSS [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-width), a percentage on the `width` property refers to the width of the containing block.

In this situation I'd intuitively expect the excess width to be shared by the two cells. However, I haven't found anything in the Tables section of the specification that describes the definitive behavior in such a case.

**Question:** What is the definitive behavior here according to CSS specifications?

**Note:** I'm not looking for "fixed" versions of this code. I just want to understand the behavior of this code as it is based on the official CSS specification.

Comment: Did not down vote, but your code isn't CSS.

Answer (score 1):

As I guess, when the table has `width:auto` or even `width:100%` how is it possible that two `td` having `width:100%` in same table.? which means `100%+100% = 200%`. Simply second `td` has no width as first `td` already took the available width trying to get `100%` and remaining space goes to second `td`.

We may set the table-layout to fixed. See the snippet.

```css
table{table-layout:fixed}
td {border:1px solid #ddd;}
```

```html
    <table style="border:1px solid black;width:100%;">
    <tr>
     <td style="width:100%;">hello.</td>
     <td style="width:100%;">World</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a definitive answer, not a guess. I need to understand the exact behavior definition of the code I showed, not a modified version.